# Django: How to iterate a recordset for a choices field that doesn't fail on testing with sqlite?

Tags: django, sqlite, unit-testing

I'm trying to make tests using an in-memory sqlite database (Django 1.6):

[settings/test.py]:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": ":memory:",
        "USER": "",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "",
        "PORT": "",
    },
}
```

I need to pass the following to a choice field

```
def VERSIONS():
    v_win_car = Version.objects.filter(
        platform='WIN',
        section='CAR',
        language='EN').order_by('-official_date')[:5]
    VCAR = [[b.version + '-' + b.section, b.version + '-' + b.section] for b in
            v_win_car]

    v_win_bike = Version.objects.filter(
        platform='WIN',
        section='BIKE',
        language='EN').order_by('-official_date')[:5]
    VBIKE = [[b.version + '-' + b.section, b.version + '-' + b.section] for b in
             v_win_bike]

    return VCAR + VBIKE
```

(Now it's enclosed in a function as I was trying to workaround this problem, at first it was simply
    VERSIONS = VCAR + VBIKE)

In the form:

```
version = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VERSIONS())
```

If I run the tests with the local settings and a mysql database it doesn't complain, but when I use the testing settings with the sqlite database it fails (also using a sqlite database file test.db):

```
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: control.tests.test_views (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: control.tests.test_views
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/compdealer16/compdealer/control/tests/test_views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from control.views import VistaJsonGetNextVersion, crear_VERSIONS
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/compdealer16/compdealer/control/views.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .forms import RenoveForm, AddEquipmentForm, AddSoftwareForm, QueryForm
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/compdealer16/compdealer/control/forms.py", line 309, in <module>
    class AddEquipmentForm(forms.Form):
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/compdealer16/compdealer/control/forms.py", line 338, in AddEquipmentForm
    version = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VERSIONS())
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/compdealer16/compdealer/control/forms.py", line 57, in VERSIONS
    v_win_car]
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealerRC/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such table: versiones_version


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

As I understand, it tries to evaluate the recordset at import time when the table hasn't been created.

Is there any way to solve this?

(Also if you find a better title for this question...)

Comment: show us your all settings and the project tree

Comment: @lalo, my base settings are [link](http://pastebin.com/Qd25790V) and the added test settings are [link](http://pastebin.com/Zw6H1fAn).

Comment: @lalo, [This is the tree of the full app](http://pastebin.com/wQQHFH3v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField):

```
version = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Version.objects.filter(...))
```

Option 2: change your choices just right after you create your form (or in it's constructor):

```
form = MyForm()
form.fields['version'].choices = ((1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'))
```

(It is considered better to query your db each time you create the form)

Comment: Thanks @Udi, I had used the first option in cases where I could use a queryset. In that case, using ModelChoiceField solves the problem.

Comment: But is the second option what has allowed me to create a customized list from the database without making tests fail with SQLite. Thanks a lot!